# What does this error mean (while event modification)?

Tags: iphone, events, calendar

Hi all I am using below code to create an event :

EKEvent *oneLabEvent = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];

```
oneLabEvent.calendar = eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents;
oneLabEvent.title = [ddEvent valueForKey:@"ddname"];
oneLabEvent.allDay = NO;

oneLabEvent.startDate = [ddEvent valueForKey:@"startDate"];
oneLabEvent.endDate = [ddEvent valueForKey:@"endDate"];


//setting the alarm for the event

EKAlarm * alarm = [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:0];
oneLabEvent.alarms = [NSArray arrayWithObject:alarm];

//setting the Reuccurence rule
EKRecurrenceRule * recurrenceRule = [[EKRecurrenceRule alloc] 
                                     initRecurrenceWithFrequency:EKRecurrenceFrequencyMonthly
                                     interval:1
                                     end:nil];
if (oneLabEvent.endDate != nil) {
    EKRecurrenceEnd * end = [EKRecurrenceEnd recurrenceEndWithEndDate:oneLabEvent.endDate];
    recurrenceRule.recurrenceEnd = end;
}else {
    oneLabEvent.endDate = oneLabEvent.startDate;
}



oneLabEvent.recurrenceRule = recurrenceRule;
[recurrenceRule release];

NSError *error;

BOOL saved = [eventStore saveEvent:oneLabEvent span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&error];
if (!saved && error) {
    NSLog(@"Error while saving the event:%@",[error localizedDescription]);
}

[ddEvent setValue:oneLabEvent.eventIdentifier forKey:@"eventID"];
```

in my phone it works like a charm but when a friend in his iphone tries modifications to the event He gets this error .

[alt text http://img208.imageshack.us/img208/8850/photot.png](http://img208.imageshack.us/img208/8850/photot.png)

Now can anyone tell me that is anything wrong with my code or is there any calendar settings that can be different from my phone and friend phone .

Comment: What are the start end end dates? Looks like the event takes longer than the repeat interval... Maybe check the years.

Comment: you can see the start and end date in the image above . it is not proper but you can see it though . but in iphone there is no problem with the modifications .

Comment: start - 14 august , repeat- monthly , interval-1, end repeat aug 14 2023

Comment: Please see my answer and debug :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your start end end dates are from different years. 14th August is a Saturday this year, but your end date shows **Moday** for 14th August.

So it is from another year, making it longer than one month, which is your repeat interval.

Comment: yes I have checked that but when I do the same settings in my phone it doesn't trigger any error and accepts as it is .

Comment: The dates are wrong... and they must come from somewhere. Your repeat section shows that 14th Aug 2023 is a Monday. Maybe this is related and you somehow managed to populate the event.endDate with that value.